# Angular router with popup

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm currently working on an app where a button triggers a method that will emit an event to elsewhere. This works great, however I also want to add a url to trigger this action.

So currently my button looks like this

```
<a class="addJob" ng-click="addNewJob()" ng-controller="AddJobController"></a>
```

But what I really want is it to just be

```
<a class="addJob" href="/new"></a>
```

Now, I can't figure out how to do the routing for this. It would mean that when I go to `/new`,  the `AddJobController` should be triggered.
When I go directly to `http://www.example.com/new`, it should still load the page properly and trigger that action.

I don't want to create a separate page for this route as it is an essential part of the app flow.

(Think of it like when you create a new note in trello.com)

Answer (score 1):

**One Option**

If you are willing to move to uiRouter, this is a common pattern.

Copied and pasted directly from the uiRouter FAQ

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state

```
$stateProvider.state("items.add", {
url: "/add",
onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "items/add",
        resolve: {
          item: function() { new Item(123).get(); }
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'item', function($scope, item) {
          $scope.dismiss = function() {
            $scope.$dismiss();
          };

          $scope.save = function() {
            item.update().then(function() {
              $scope.$close(true);
            });
          };
        }]
    }).result.then(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            return $state.transitionTo("items");
        }
    });
}]
})
```

**Second Option**

The second options would be to launch the modal the constructor of your controller. I have included a modalFactory. This is a common pattern. It allows your modals to be reusable, and cleans up your controllers. The uiRouter example above should use the factory pattern as well to abstract the modal setup out of the state config.

This example should work with ngRouter.

```
app.controller('addJobModalController', ['modalFactory', function(modalFactory) {

    modalFactory.addJob();

}]);



app.factory('modalFactory', ['$modal', function($modal) {

    return {
        addJob: function() {
            return $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/addjob-modal.html',
                controller: 'AddJobController',
                size: 'md'
            });
        }
    }

}]);
```

The addJob() method returns the modal's promise. If you want, you can store this promise in the factory to be returned by another method so that another controller or service can act on the result of the modal.

Comment: I'm not using the uiRouter, I'm using the default ngRoute

Comment: I updated the answer to add a more generic solution if moving to uiRouter is not an option.